# Uninitialized Value from Double Pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, infinite-loop, double-pointer

I'm newer to C and working on a project that requires manipulating a wset (WordSet) object, which is essentially just an array of WordNode objects, themselves a representation of words (they contain a count int, so instead of duplicate WordNode objects, existing WordNode's count is incremented)

In implementing a basic search method, I'm not initializing some aspect of a double pointer WordNode, as checking test through Valgrind shows the use of (*p) seen below is allowing memory leak, through either not being malloc'd or free'd (I think the latter is less likely).

I want to see if I'm implementing this incorrectly or if my problem exists outside of this block of code, most likely in the original allocation of memory for the creation.

```
static WordNode **search (WordSet *wset, char *word) {
 WordNode **p;
 p = &((wset)->head);
  char *pWord = (*p)->word;
  while((*p) != NULL){
  //if the words we're trying to find and our word match...
  //...break and return the address
      if(strcmp(pWord,word)==0){
        break;
      }
      p = &((*p)->next);
  }
  return p;
}
```

Any errors seem to trace to here and debug was performed through valgrind, as some changes (especially in regards to the (*p)) result in valgrind never completing when it gets stuck in an infinite of the while loop.

I believe my existing written tests would be irrelevant, and the problem can be found in this block of code. However if additional context would help elaborate I'll try and add it!

Comment: Try here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "memory leak" would mean not freeing something... you can't leak memory you don't allocate in the first place.  Also, the block of code you show neither allocates nor frees anything.  It looks like it's probably got other problems, but it's hard to tell without seeing more code... (Why is `pWord` only set before the loop that checks it? etc.)

Comment: This function isn't being used to modify the pointer you use to free your array later, is it?